# How to access node_modules folder after running yarn_install (or npm_install ) in rules_nodejs bazel?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules-nodejs

I'm relatively new to Bazel but this has taken longer than I felt it should. I am doing `yarn_install` in my workspace, and I am just trying to reference the installed `node_modules` so that I can put them in my new docker container.

**Workspace**

```
yarn_install(
    name = "npm",
    package_json = "//:package.json",
    yarn_lock = "//:yarn.lock",
)
```

**BUILD.bazel**

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//nodejs:image.bzl", "nodejs_image")

nodejs_image(
    name = "webapi_image",
    # gets all the files in my directory
    data = glob(
        [
            "**/*",
        ],
        # references the node modules, but doesn't work :(
    ) + ["@npm//node_modules"],
    entry_point = "//:app.js",
)
```

I've been able to get specific packages (i.e. `@npm//express`) but if I try to access node_modules  then I just get

`no such package '@npm//node_modules': Package is considered deleted due to --deleted_packages and referenced by '//:webapi_image'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand why I can access individual packages (i.e. `@npm//express`) but not node_modules (i.e. `@npm//node_modules`).

but after bumping around, I found if I just use the structure `@npm//:node_modules`, then it works finally.